# JMX - Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jmx, cloud-foundry

I am having a java app which I am planning to migrate to Pivotal Cloud Foundry. The application uses JMX to change of the properties at runtime. Is it possible to retain the same architecture when I migrate the app to PCF or should I explore a different approach?

Comment: I am facing the same problem now, do you remember the approach for this issue?

Comment: @grindlewald I ended up using spring cloud configuration server for this use case

Comment: I also used actuator as suggested in the other answer for other use cases and didn’t have to use jmx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a PCF app, the cloud environment should provide dependencies needed for your app. You can inject these dependencies for runtime in various ways, for instance, provide environment settings.

If you need say credentials at runtime, you can look at Spring Cloud Services, and the Config server. If you are looking for other services, you can use Service registry and discovery (based on Netflix Eureka component) within Spring Cloud Services.

It all depends on your use case. 
Can you elaborate more on "change properties at runtime"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I wanted to check if I can access JMX runtime of java apps deployed in CF.

Comment: The question is asked about JMX configuration on PCF

Answer (score 1):

are you using Spring Boot in your Java app? If so, you can use JMX features with Actuator. Jolokia helps you to do this via JMX over HTTP. 
Please refer: [Spring Boot JMX Management](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-jmx.html)

If this is a traditional Java App, you have pushed into PCF, you can use Java build pack features to enable JMX. 
Please refer: [Enable JMX port via Java Build Pack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-jmx.md)

Please try and let us know how it goes.